# How to login with both password and fingerprint?

Tags: security, pam, fingerprint

**How to configure PAM to require both password and fingerprint to log in?**

I can do a password / fingerprint login but not both by changing `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`

1. For password only

   ```
   auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
   ```
2. For fingerprint only

   ```
   auth [success=2 default=ignore] pam_fprintd.so
   ```

How to combine both?

Comment: related post: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207360/use-multiple-pam-login-methods-at-once

Comment: login with ssh?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `success=2` control flag PAM skips the next 2 items in the stack on success. And `default=ignore` means you ignore bad results, so depending on your [configuration](https://linux.die.net/man/5/pam.conf) you should probably use success=ok on the first entry and default=bad on both as they are executed in order.

```
auth    [success=ok default=bad]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    [success=2 default=bad]   pam_fprintd.so
```

This would require both password (pam_unix) and fingerprint (pam_fprintd) and only succeeds if both are successful. If you want to cancel the checks after first failure, you can also use `default=die` which is equivalent to bad but terminates the PAM stack immediately.